# Imprimir dato de acuerdo al Id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

me podrían ayudar con esto?, debo imprimir las imágenes agrupadas de acuerdo al post_id, pero no se como hacerlo. post_id es de la tabla post, en la cual esta la descripción del grupo de imágenes.
 [image]

Esto es lo que tengo en mi controlador en el método index

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $photos = Photo::all()->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    return view('profile.index', compact('photos'));
}
```

En el index, intente imprimir, pero imprime todas las imágenes por separadas, repitiendo en cada una la descripción

```
<div class="card-body">
@foreach ($photos as $post)
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
            <div class="post">
                <p>
                    {{ implode(',', $post->post()->get()->pluck('description')->toArray())}}
                </p>

                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                        <a href="images/{{$post->file }}" class="fancybox" rel="ligthbox" style="width:90%; height:70%">
                            <img src="images/{{$post->file }}" class="zoom img-fluid" alt="" style="width:90%; height:100%">
                        </a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Deseas una consulta que te traiga todas las imágenes de acuerdo con su post_id agrupadas?

Comment: @Aprendiz exacto, agrupadas según el post_id

Comment: @Aprendiz si, alli se almacena las imagenes junto con el pos_id

Comment: Un post puede tener muchas imágenes y una img puede pertenecer a un post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi respuesta parte considerando que en el modelo `Post`tienes la siguiente relación:

```
class Post extends Model 
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

Posterior en el modelo `Photo` tienes la siguiente relación:

```
class Photo extends Model 
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Entonces puedes hacer uso de *eager loading* para cargar todos los imágenes con sus posts con los cuales están relacionadas así y al final le encadenas el método `groupBy()` al cual le pasas como argumento el nombre de la columna por la cual deseas agrupar que en este caso sería `post_id`

```
$imagenes = Photo::with('post')->get()->groupBy('post_id');
```